# select provisioning profile

Tags: ios, xcode

I already create the certificate, I already did everything here: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/iphone-sdk-install-apps-on-iphone-devices-for-development/

and I still cant select the profile:

https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/qczMPnI94oVuiItodzOQtxc5iP7SJH_6L1rtc6AwQZcoCBjoKhfh1v5S0TNRH6xRc1xxbHNJbnE

I'm using xcode 4.2
why I cant select the profiles ?

Comment: more info: I did this too:
[link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/ios_development_workflow/20-Building_and_Running_Applications/building_and_running_applications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007959-CH6-SW2)

but this ( [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/ios_development_workflow/art/code_signing_identity_options.jpg) ) does not happen.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason why this would happen is you are selecting the wrong profile for the specific field (for example, when you try to use a "distribution profile" for debugging or "developing profile" for release. It should have been the other way around, obviously) So double check the profiles you have created, if they are created for the right reasons (debugging or distribution).

To make life simplier, you can also just always pick in the rows below "Automatic Profile Selector". If you have at least one profile in the category, you can run the app with no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have installed certificate and mobile provisioning profile correctly. Open Xcode organiser, select devices, select provisioning profiles under library and you should see corresponding profile has valid certificate with Valid Profile status. If that's correct and bundle identifier in the mobile provisioning profile and in your project settings(plist) matching then you will be able to select profile definitely.